# Change connection NAME using it's DEVICE name, while down - nmcli ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli

I am trying something that looks very easy/simple, but since i put my question here, it's looking to be more difficult then i thought.

I have to configure edge pc's (in batches, 5-10 each couple months), all fine except for the fact that i want to give the network cards some more descriptive names.

The edge pc's running Ubuntu 22.04 have 2 ethernet ports. One we use for network A and another for network B. Upon configuration i already bring back these network cards to standard value's, where the device chances to eth0 and eth1, using:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"/g' /etc/default/grub

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

nmcli device and nmcli connection output:

[image]

Lets say i want to change the NAME for DEVICE eth0 to : NWA and the NAME for DEVICE eth1 to : NWB.
I have not found a way to do this, since this commmand requires ID or UUID or NAME:

```
nmcli connection modify 'some name 1' con-name NWA
```

The problem is, i don't know what will be the NAME beforehand, and can't find a link between the NAME and the DEVICE, Using 'nmcli device' does give me a link between the active/connected network card, but not the ones unavailable. Which doesn't help me.

I hope someone here would have an idea how to tackle this seemingly easy problem.

Greetings

Mattijs

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do, it annoys the dogs.